# calculating age when textbox is empty error

Tags: c#

i have 2 texboxes textbox71 in it i enter the date of birth and the program calculates the age for me and show it in textbox72 , the problem is when i don't enter something in textbox71 the program gives me an error "string was not recognized as valid datetime " and shuts down , what i want from the program is when i dont enter something in dateofbirth textbox to show me a message to enter something , so i tried to do this but it didnt work here is my code :

```
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox71.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("please enter date of birth");
            }
            else
            {

                DateTime drid2 = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox71.Text);
                DateTime drid3 = DateTime.Now;
                int yy1 = Math.Abs(drid3.Year - drid2.Year);
                textBox72.Text = yy1.ToString();

           }
```

Comment: two better thing (1) string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace... (2) {DateTime.Now - BirthDate).TotalDays / 365.2422} (wiki :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifing to

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox71.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("please enter date of birth");
        }
        else
        {

            DateTime drid2 = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox71.Text);
            DateTime drid3 = DateTime.Now;
            int yy1 = Math.Abs(drid3.Year - drid2.Year);
            textBox72.Text = yy1.ToString();
         }
```

!string.IsNullOrEmpty returns true if the value is not empty and false if the value is empty. And you were trying to do the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

This `string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox71.Text)` will be `true` **if** the `textBox71.Text` is either *null* or *empty*. So, `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox71.Text)` will be `false` **if** the `textBox71.Text` is either *null* or *empty*, because `!` is the negation operator.

So when the `textBox71.Text` would be either *null* or *empty*, the code in the `else` statement will be executed and when it will reach the line

```
DateTime drid2 = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox71.Text);
```

you will get an error, because `textBox71.Text` would be either *null* or *empty*.

So removing the negation operator `!`, your logic would be correct and your code would be executed as you expect.

For more information about the logical negation operator, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2kd6eb2.aspx).

I would suggest you use the method `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, since it is more general:

> Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only of white-space characters.

For more information about this method, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).